# Can you send pre-selected drop down data to google sheet via AppScripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm collecting some lead data into a google sheet on form submission. I followed this tutorial to get the basics going https://measureschool.com/google-sheets-tracking-google-tag-manager/

But I need to send over drop-down data OR copy and paste a drop-down from another cell in my "Lead Status" column and have the selection of the drop-down map to the data provided. For instance, if I send over "Customer", Customer would be selected in the drop-down. But I'm having issues making that work. Here is a modification I made below but the field is blank when passing data over...

```
function handleResponse(e, sheetId) {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_KEY);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = [];
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else if (headers[i] == "Lead Status") { // write Lead Status value to appropriate column
        // get the range of the column you want to set validation for
        var range = sheet.getRange(2, i+1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
        
        // set the validation rule for the range
        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
          .requireValueInList(["Marketing Qualified", "Sales Qualified", "Sales Opportunity", "Customer", "Lost"], true)
          .setAllowInvalid(false)
          .build();
        range.setDataValidation(rule);

        // set the value of the cell
        row.push(e.parameter["Lead Status"]);
      } else {
        // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow,"SHEET_KEY": SHEET_KEY,"SHEET_EVENT_KEY": SHEET_EVENT_KEY,"test":"test" }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e, "test":"test"}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
```

From what I have read my data validation should be working... but it isn't... any help would be appreciated. My thanks in advance.

Comment: [This happens to me](https://imgur.com/vHGoveM) when trying this code and there are ways to update it but I don't know how it should look like. Could you please share an example of the URL parameters that you're using (for example: ?Lead Status=Customer&Value1=value1) and an example of how you would like the resulting row to look like?

Comment: Yes, sure "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz_zggxv63WDPaJvo9qfxBn4ARBEg56RHy9s8Py-vFhSx6lH0rSsTNJVrj1D-K9RkU/exec?Lead%20Status=Customer&First%20Name=John&FL%20Session%20ID=2222&sheetId=1BKeiQIP9ckl4q_BeHieJtDShL5Gke5Zcg_YbmAq3Tjw" thats basically what I want to do...and in that sheet (L2) you can see how I was expecting it to function. I want to be able to have a functioning dropdown with "Customer" Or "MQL" pre selected

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry if I was not clear enough, the sample URL will be helpful but could you also share an example (either a link to a sanitized Google Sheet document or screenshot) showing how the Sheet's Range looks when processing those parameters with the current code and how it should look like when these parameters are processed correctly?

Comment: Sure, here is a sheet where L2 has a drop-down,  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PuIO-u-Ur8A58d6lvSOCsUuj5vLwNiwBMHX6mi4kBI/edit#gid=0

I post (GET) to said sheet like so:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz_zggxv63WDPaJvo9qfxBn4ARBEg56RHy9s8Py-vFhSx6lH0rSsTNJVrj1D-K9RkU/exec?Lead%20Status=Customer&First%20Name=John&FL%20Session%20ID=2222&sheetId=18PuIO-u-Ur8A58d6lvSOCsUuj5vLwNiwBMHX6mi4kBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would like to add all the entered values into the table and make sure that the Data Valitadion at `L2` is used under ***Lead Stage***, I modified the **for loop** to work based on that:

```
for (i in headers) {
  if (headers[i] == "Date Added") { // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
    row.push(new Date());
  } else if (headers[i] == "Lead Stage") { // write Lead Status value to appropriate column
    // get the range of the column you want to set validation for
    var range = sheet.getRange(nextRow, parseInt(i) + 1);

    // set the validation rule for the range
    // var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    //   .requireValueInList(["Marketing Qualified", "Sales Qualified", "Sales Opportunity", "Customer", "Lost"], true)
    //   .setAllowInvalid(false)
    //   .build();
    sheet.getRange('L2').copyTo(range);
    // set the value of the cell
    row.push(e.parameter["Lead Stage"]);
  } else {
    // else use header name to get data
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
  }
}
```

#### Please note:

1. The code was updated to use "Date Added" instead of "Timestamp" and "Lead Stage" instead of "Lead Status" to match the names in your Google Sheet file.
2. I opted to copy the whole L2 cell into the new appropriate range instead of re-creating and re-applying the whole Data Validation rule.
3. The following line had to be updated:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2, i+1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
```

Apps Script was not recognizing `ì` as an int so normal operations would cause the result to be "12+1 = 121" for example, using `parseInt()` solves this issue, I also changed it so that we would only affect the new cell being created:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(nextRow, parseInt(i) + 1);
```

This is how it looks after a few calls to the Web App:

[image]

Comment: First, Thank you! This works, but for my own curiosity is there any way to use  Array and validate against it? Or do you need to use a pre-defined field in the sheet?